# I don't think I'm modifying this collection

Tags: c#, list, object, collections

Code:

```
    List<Item> Contents = ObjectHandler.player.Contents.ToList<Item>() //Was HashTable
    List<int> IDS = new List<int>(); //Holds Item IDs for later counting
    foreach (Item I in Contents) 
    {
        IDS.Add(I.ID); // Add ID to IDS
    }
    List<Item> newContents = Contents;
    foreach (Item I in Contents)
    {
        if (IDS.Contains(I.ID)) //Check if the ID has already been used in Contents
        {
            newContents.Remove(I); //Remove it
        }
    }
    Contents = newContents;
```

This Code snippet should prepare a list of IDs for later counting, and also remove duplicates from a list of Items. However, as soon as an item is present in *Contents*, however, I recieve an *InvalidOperationException*. I'm fairly certain I'm not modifying Contents, which the *foreach* is looping through, thus my confusion. Could somebody explain this to me? thanks.

Comment: BTW, that will remove _all_ items, not just duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
newContents = Contents;
```

You now have two variables pointing to the same collection.

You probably want to copy the collection by writing `new List<Item>(Contents)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Contents = ObjectHandler.player.Contents.ToList<Item>();
var IDs = new HashSet<int>();
var filtered = Contents.Where( i =>
  {
      bool result = !IDs.Contains(i.ID);
      IDs.Add(i.ID);
      return result;
  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although @SLaks points out a good way to copy the list and avoid having the two objects point to the same place, there is no need for two lists in the first place.

If you use a traditional for loop (rather than foreach) and count backwards, you can remove the items from the original list without anything complaining.

Something along the lines of below should work:

```
for (int i = Contents.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (IDS.Contains(Contents[i].ID)) //Check if the ID has already been used in Contents
    {
        Contents.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, can anyone point out the best way to reference someone else in a response?  I didn't see any button like the blockquote or similar that would do it.